# Python Pandas filter by date on load

Tags: python, pandas

I've read a few posts about using thinks like skiprows and chunk size to load a CSV incrementally but nothing has fit my particular use case. Ideally I would like something that works like a push down predicate.

I have a large csv (8.6 million rows) and would only like to load data from the past week. There's a field in the file that designates date, and I am currently loading the entire df, then filtering by date. I'm not sure if it's possible to skip loading the old records altogether but that would be my aim. Is that doable?

EDIT: Here's the code I'm using:

```
import boto3

S3Client = boto3.client('s3','us-east-1')

obj = S3Client.get_object(Bucket = 'bucket_name', Key = 'some_key')
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
```

and the data is formatted as such:

```
|'Cust_ID'|'Type'|'Date_of_activity'|'Amount'|'Item_count'|'time_of_order'|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1234     |OL    |12-12-2019        |1234    |10          |23:34          |
|5678     |IS    |12-12-2019        |8765    |50          |11:34          |
|9101     |OL    |12-13-2019        |1504    |17          |3:45           |
```

I'm doing this for 2 separate CSVs, both have about 8-10 million records in each.

I am doing some joining, filtering, and aggregating after loading the data frames which is significantly easier to do in pandas as opposed to using just the standard CSV module. I don't think `chunk_size` will work because from what I have read it won't actually allow me to filter based on the `'Date_of_activity'` it just loads a certain number of rows at a time.

Essentially the situation is that we are receiving a total/complete historical data dump every week when in reality what we need is just the orders from the previous week.

Comment: What’s wrong with loading all the data and then filtering in Pandas?

Comment: It takes about 6 minutes to load the data frame because it has about 10 million records and I only need about 120k of them. Just trying to reduce time/cost

Comment: How large is the file/data as a whole?

Comment: After doing some thinking and research, I have a few questions for you: Have you done any benchmarking or profiling? You write that creating an iterator with `chunk_size` doesn’t fit you use case, why is that? I thought that it would be a great fit for this problem. Are you specifying all the column dtypes? What are you doing to parse the dates themselves? Have you tried the `memory_map` option? Have you considered using the basic `csv` module instead of Pandas, since you don’t need the powerful features of the latter?

Comment: I wrote earlier that it would be great if you shared more about the data. I will add that having your code, or even part of it, would be of great help. All in all, this is a nice question, I hope it goes somewhere. Similar questions on the subject seem to have mostly old and outdated answers. I would love to be able to try out a bunch of different things and produce a large, solid answer which could be useful to many people.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I just updated the question with code, sample data, and more context.

Comment: That's not what the CSV file actually looks like, right? I just want something that I can copy/paste easily lol

Comment: Another thing, is the `time_of_order` on the day indicated in `date_of_activity`?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile that's sample data that is reflective of what the CSV actually looks like. `date_of_activity` is only a date field and `time_of_order` is only a time field, the time is not indicated in the date

Comment: Ah that’s too bad, would have been cool if we could just slap the two together.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [dask dataframe](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html).

It will only compute what you explicitly tell it to, without the need of loading the entire dataframe to memory.

Comment: You mean without needing to load the DataFrame to _memory_, right?

Comment: This could work. I'm trying to optimize a lambda function though and im not sure dask is viable within lambda. I may just look into other AWS services

Comment: @DBA108642 It should work for this application, especially since you are partitioning by date.  Load the dask dataframe and run your operation as you normally would.  It will probably run much faster if date is your index.  See docs: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html

Comment: @bwc the data is received as a flat csv so it doesn't have any partitions.

Comment: @DBA108642 Speaking of, could you share part of the data? Or at least something representative, so that we can better understand the situation.